# Contract communication between consumer/producer in SOAP vs REST?

Tags: java, rest, soap, wsdl, wadl

I have worked mostly on SOAP based web services as of now. In word of soap, producer used the WSDL to convey the structure of message to consumer.

Learnt recently REST based web services where i do find much different in terms of usage (Yes internals are totally different) from consumer/producer perspective.

My question is how producer  conveys the structure of message to consumer as there is WSDL type stuff here. I believe WADL is there but thats not standard as of now ?
Does producer convey in form of java class(if java based consumner) or dot net based class(if dot net based producer) here or WADL is standard here?

Answer (score 0):

WADL https://wadl.java.net/ and OData http://www.odata.org/ are both emerging standards